# Swift enum associated values in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums, swift3

1. Is there a way to use new Swift3 enums with associated value in Objective-C?
2. Is there a way to declare/bridge Swift3 enums with associated value in Objective-C, if I develop a library and want to give Swift3 users convenient API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible, Apple has a list of *Swift Type Compatibility* which explicitly excludes enumerations defined in Swift without `Int` raw value type.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID53)

Comment: Can you list some possible alternates?

Answer (score 4):

This is what I did:

In Swift class created the enum

```
enum Origin {
    case Search(searchTerm: String, searchResultsPageNum: Int)
    case Discovery(pageNum: Int)
}
```

Then in my Class, created enum property and functions (that are visible to Objective C) to set and get values of the enum property.

```
@objc class GameSession: NSObject
{
    ...

    var gameOrigin: Origin?

    ...

    let originStr = "origin"
    let notSpecified = "Not Specified"

    @objc func getOrigin() -> NSDictionary
    {
        guard let origin = gameOrigin else {
            return [originStr: notSpecified]
        }

        switch origin {
        case .Search(let searchTerm, let searchResultsPageNum):
            return ["searchTerm": searchTerm, "searchResultsPageNum": "\(searchResultsPageNum)"]
        case .Discovery(let pageNum)
            return ["pageNum": pageNum]
        default:
            return [originStr: notSpecified]
        }
    }

    @objc func setSearchOriginWith(searchTerm: String, searchResultsPageNum: Int, filtered:Bool)
    {
        self.gameOrigin = Origin.Search(searchTerm: searchTerm, searchResultsPageNum: searchResultsPageNum, filtered: filtered)
    }

    @objc func setDiscoveryOriginWith(pageNum: Int)
    {
        self.gameOrigin = Origin.Discovery(pageNum: pageNum)
    }

}
```