# Expose Swift Array Of Enums in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums, nativescript

I have this enum in swift

```
@objc(PaymentMethods)
public enum PaymentMethods: Int, RawRepresentable {
    public typealias RawValue = String
    case card
    case account
    case paypal

    public var rawValue: RawValue {
        switch self {
        case .card:
            return "CARD"
        case .account:
            return "ACCOUNT"
        case .paypal:
            return "PAYPAL"
        }
    }

    public init(rawValue: RawValue){
        switch rawValue {
        case "CARD":
            self = .card
        case "ACCOUNT":
            self = .account
        case "PAYPAL":
            self = .paypal
        default:
            self = .card
        }
    }
}
```

And this property in a class.

```
@objc public class SomeClass: ExtendingSomeOtherStuffs {
  var supportedPaymentMethods:[PaymentMethods]!
}
```

my problem is how to bridge `supportedPaymentMethods` into Objective-C and use it.

I have looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30453961/bridging-an-array-of-enums-from-swift-to-objective-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129941/swift-enum-associated-values-in-objective-c) but still can't figure it out.
can someone help me out with an example at least.

Am trying to use this in Native-script and I need to expose that property from Swift to Objective

Comment: What Objective-C code do you have?

Comment: @RomanPodymov I don't have access to Objective-C code but thats generated behind the scenes of Nativescript. I just need to be sure that the property will be bridged to objective c

Comment: BTW, as an aside, the enumeration definition appears unusual.  `PaymentMethods : Int` would normally mean the raw values are of type `Int`, yet they are re-defined, somewhat artificially, to be `String`.  Also, you didn't have to specify `RawRepresentable`, it's implied, but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: Have you placed the swift files inside the project Or compiled it as a framework? Did you try generating typings?

Comment: @Manoj it has been compiled as a Framework. When I generate typings it does not include any property that is of type Array of Enums. Just like above

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
@objc public class SomeClass: NSObject {
    var supportedPaymentMethods: [PaymentMethods]
    
    @objc init(supportedPaymentMethods: [String]) {
        self.supportedPaymentMethods = supportedPaymentMethods.map { .init(rawValue: $0) }
    }
}
```

and use it like this in your Objective-C code:

```
[[SomeClass alloc] initWithSupportedPaymentMethods:@[@"ACCOUNT", @"CARD", @"PAYPAL"]];
```

---

If you don't want your class initializer to take any `String` I would suggest doing the following:

1. Make your `init(rawValue:)` failable and return `nil` when the argument is invalid:

```
public init?(rawValue: RawValue) {
        switch rawValue {
        case "CARD":
            self = .card
        case "ACCOUNT":
            self = .account
        case "PAYPAL":
            self = .paypal
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
```

2. Use `compactMap` instead of `map` in the init of the `SomeClass` like so:

```
@objc init(supportedPaymentMethods: [String]) {
        self.supportedPaymentMethods = supportedPaymentMethods.compactMap { .init(rawValue: $0) }
    }
```

(it will eliminate the nil values)